# How to use _.filter to sort by name and ranking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have the following:

```
Emojis = {
  ':smile:' : { people: true, ranking: 1 },
  ':gring:' : { people: true, ranking: 2 },
  ':wink:' : { people: true, ranking: 3 },
  ':smirk:' : { people: true }
};

EmojiNames = _.keys(Emojis);

EmojiCommon = _.filter(EmojiNames, function (name) {
  if (Emojis[name].people) {
    return name;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Right now, I have EmojiCommon, returning items that match the name == "people" how can I have the EmojiCommon function also filter by ranking. Where item 1 would be first and anything without a ranking below all items with a ranking?

Comment: `_.filter` has nothing to do with sorting. It looks like you want to use JavaScript's native sort method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort or Underscore's `_.sortBy`: http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add an additional step to sort. This sorts first by rank, and then by name. You can reverse the arguments of `||` to sort by name, then by rank.

```
Emojis = {
  ':wink:' : { people: true, ranking: 3 },
  ':gring:' : { people: true, ranking: 2 },
  ':smirk:' : { people: true },
  ':smile:' : { people: true, ranking: 1 }
};

EmojiNames = _.keys(Emojis);

EmojiCommon = _.filter(EmojiNames, function (name) {
  return Emojis[name].people;
});

EmojiCommon.sort(function(a,b) {
  var rankA = Emojis[a].ranking || Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var rankB = Emojis[b].ranking || Number.MAX_VALUE;
  return (rankA - rankB) || (a > b ? 1 : -1);
});

console.log(EmojiCommon)
```

`a` and `b` in `.sort` are strings. If one compares two strings with `<`, they are compared alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to show the full solution?

Comment: Also, where does this function sort by name?

Comment: @AnApprentice Just add it to the end of your snippet.

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles he doesn't, and it does

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't let me specify the name. I have a long list of emojis and want to specify just those that match people.

Comment: oops thought he was using non native

Comment: @AnApprentice You need both `_.filter` and `.sort`. `.sort` doesn't do filtering, and vice-versa.

Comment: I'm not following. Can you show the full solution? Are you saying your answer is an add-on?

Comment: Thanks! that works without an error but the results are not sorted, I'm not seeing any change when I call CL.EmojiCommon in the js console.

Comment: @AnApprentice You probably wanted the `rank` to be in ascending order. Answer updated.

Comment: @AnApprentice Try again

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, objects do not have any guarantee of ordering.  What you really want, then, is an array.  You have a couple of options.  You can use an array to start off with:

```
var emojis = [
    { key: ':smile:', people: true, ranking: 1 },
    { key: ':gring:', people: true, ranking 2 },
    { key: ':wink:', people: true, ranking: 3 },
    { key: ':smirk:', people: true }
];
```

Then you can filter & sort:

```
var filtered = emojis.filter(function(x) { return x.people; });
filtered.sort(function(a,b) { return a.ranking - b.ranking });
```

If you're stuck with your object (i.e., you have a lot of other code relying on that), you can convert it to an array using Underscore's `pairs` method:

```
var emojis = _.pairs(Emojis);
```

Then you just need some additional indirection:

```
var filtered = emojis.filter(function(x) { return x[1].people; });
filtered.sort(function(a,b) { return a[1].ranking - b[1].ranking });
```

Note that it's not necessary to use Underscore's `filter` method: the built in JavaScript `filter` method works just fine for your application.

In the comments, it's pointed out that `Array.prototype.filter` is an ES5.1 feature, so if you need to support really old browser (IE8 or below are notable examples), you'll have to polyfill it:

```
if(!Array.prototype.filter) Array.prototype.filter = function(f,t){
    var ret = [];
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
        if (t===undefined?f(this[i]):f.call(t,this[i])) {
            ret.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain, @Enjoys Turtles?  I've never heard that.  What do you mean by non-ECMA 5?  *Older* versions of ECMA?  That would be crazy.  And as far as I know, the behavior of sort is not changing in ES6, so...I'm really confused by what you mean (or where you're getting your facts).

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles: Then it's a good thing that `Array.prototype.sort` [was already around in ES1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Specifications).

Comment: DERP, i meant filter, accidentally typed what I read - filter is the ECMA 5 one

Comment: Ah.  Yes.  Well, `filter` has been around for a while now, and is implemented in almost all browsers with a market share above 1%.  AND it's super easy to polyfill if it isn't there.